# Use index in ORDER BY query SQLite

Tags: index, index-tuning, sqlite

I have a table that store messages for my Chat app:

```
CREATE TABLE message (
    currentUserId,
    threadId,
    timestamp,
    message,
    msgType,
    msgState )
```

Then I used this query to load 20 message for each thread:

```
SELECT rowid, * FROM message WHERE currentUserId = '123' AND threadId = '456' ORDER BY timestamp LIMIT 50, 20
```

So which index should I create to optimize loading speed of this query?

I already try to index in each of these approaches but none of them seem to be working:

- timestamp
- threadId
- (threadId, timestamp)

Comment: Index on `(currentuser ID, threadid, timestamp) `

Answer (score 1):

As ypercube mentioned, you'll want to create your index on all three fields, `currentUserId`, `threadId` and `timestamp` like so: `CREATE  INDEX IX_YourIndexName ON message (currentUserId, threadId, timestamp)`. The reasoning being you should index on all fields in your predicates (`JOIN`, `WHERE`, and `HAVING` clauses) to create a fully **covering index** (see [**1.7 Covering Indices**](https://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html)) which would be the `currentUserId` and `threadId` in this case. And then also adding the fields from your `ORDER BY` clause will help sort the index on those fields as well which will reduce the work for sorting when your query runs. For more information on [indexing in SQLite](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-index/).

Note you might even see a slight performance benefit by switching around the order of `currentUserId`  and `threadId` in the index definition, assuming the `threadId` is more unique than the `currentUserId` in the table. By defining your indexes with the most unique fields first, it improves the selectivity of that index because less values need to be seeked on upfront. So if `threadId` is more unique of a field, you could try this index definition as well `CREATE  INDEX IX_YourIndexName ON message (threadId, currentUserId, timestamp)`. But unless the difference in uniqueness between `threadId` and `currentUserId` is a lot, or you have a lot of data, you probably won't notice much of a difference, so either definition should be equally fine.

Comment: First: If my query doesn't have `WHERE` clause and only has `ORDER BY`. So I will need to create index on `timestamp`, right? Does an index help to speed up when sorting?

Comment: Second: Does it different if I create an 3-columns index `(currentUserId, threadId, timestamp)`, OR create two index `(currentUserId, threadId)` and `(timestamp).

Comment: @nhoxbypass - no two datasets are ever identical - you can always test and see what works best with your own data.

Comment: @nhoxbypass If you changed your query to have no `WHERE` clause, the proposed index might help, but an additional index on just `timestamp` may be most optimal. As Verace mentions, testing will always give you the best answers. :)

Comment: Uniqueness/selectivity with order of columns is more often irrelevant in affecting the efficiency of the index in these cases - at least in other DBMSs that I've worked with. Both the first two columns are being checked with equality conditions in the WHERE clause, so the order of these 2 columns in the index does not matter.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ More often than not, the amount of data and the variance in uniqueness between the fields won't be enough for it to matter, as you've experienced, but I figured it's a good point to make people aware of as it is still true and occurs in larger datasets. I've experienced it with *big data* (specifically in Microsoft SQL Server) where the index on `ColumnA, ColumnB` resulted in it being seconds slower than on `ColumnB, ColumnA` for a simple `SELECT` on the table with both columns as predicates in the `WHERE` clause. This is because the **seek** on `ColumnB` eliminated a lot more...

Comment: ...rows upfront when traversing the index's tree, before subsequently **seeking** on `ColumnA`. Where as the reverse index, starting with `ColumnA`, would result in a lot more rows to be `seeked` first before subsequently **seeking** on `ColumnB`.

Comment: So the difference is about the variance of the dataset, not the order in WHERE clause, right?

Comment: @J.D. my point is (and my experience is mainly with SQL Server, MySQL and Postgres) that uniqueness/selectivity in `(a,b)` vs `(b,a)` index is exactly the same. I've never noticed a difference in these cases. When the indexes are `(a)` vas `(b)`, yes, selectivity matters and different datasets yield different performance between indexes..

Comment: You said *"where the index on ColumnA, ColumnB resulted in it being seconds slower than on ColumnB, ColumnA for a simple SELECT on the table with both columns as predicates in the WHERE clause."* Were the predicates equality or other (`>`, `>=`, `LIKE`,  etc)?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ I understand what you're saying. The *exact* query was `SELECT ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC FROM Table1 WHERE ColumnA = 123 AND ColumnB = 987`. The execution plans were the same, minus the difference in which index was used to **seek** on. The table itself was in the billions of records, and the predicates above probably returned millions of records (if I recall correctly). Again, I understand it's not a common case but in the example above the difference was of measurable seconds after testing both ways multiple times. The hardware of the server was modest though (e.g. 16 GB of RAM).

Comment: @J.D. Interesting. And the two indexes were both non-clustered?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Yup, nonclustered. I know the Big O for time is the same in both cases, so it should be negligible usually, but at large scales of data, there are linearly granular differences that are measurable. And in my use case for this example, the difference of a few seconds mattered since it was for a query that was called potentially multiple times a second.